# How may I enable the extra slider icon?

Tags: interactive

How may I enable the extra slider icon described here http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate.html#498667553:

[image]

Here in Wolfram Cloud in latest Google Chrome, it is absent:

[image]

EDIT: Feyre, in view of [the stated opposition to me adding a Wolfram cloud tag to a question not determined to be specific to the Wolfram cloud](https://archive.is/Agt79), I have removed the wolfram-cloud tag you added. If you're certain this question is specific to the Wolfram cloud, please feel free to re-add the tag provided you cite that evidence. Thanks.

Comment: For the record: The default controller for `Manipulate` is the `Manipulator` which doesn't seem to be supported recently (I bet it was working): `Manipulator[Dynamic[x],Appearance->"Open"]`.

Comment: About the edit ChrisJJ, how is that not wolfram-cloud specific?

Comment: I don't know that it is Wolfram Cloud specific. I haven't tried it on other platforms.

Comment: I see, it works well on desktop MMA.

Comment: @Kuba, OK, so we can at least add a "not-MMA" tag :-)

Answer (score 5):

**Example**

*Note*: This will add all them buttons as in your example but you won't be able to hide them.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}],
 {n, 1, 20, Animator}
 ]
```

In the above example I omit typing `ControlType -> Animator`, that's what you'd normally do. It seems to work without it :). I have added reference for `ControlType` below.

Also, see documentation associated with `Manipulate` function. Specifically, see ***Details and Options*** section. Below is relevant.

> The option setting ControlType->type attempts to use controls of the
>   specified type.
>
> Possible control types include: Animator, Checkbox,
>   CheckboxBar, ColorSetter, ColorSlider, FormControl, InputField,
>   Manipulator, PopupMenu, RadioButton or RadioButtonBar, Setter or
>   SetterBar, Slider, Slider2D, TogglerBar, Trigger, and VerticalSlider.
>   None can also be used. ControlType options can be given separately for
>   each variable. Options for the controls can also be given within the
>   specification for the variables.

**Output**

[image: example]

**Reference**

[Manipulate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)
[ControlType](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ControlType.html)
[Animator](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animator.html)

Comment: Thanks, but the extra slider Icon for which I asked is the one I want. But interesting to see your Animator option - I can find no documentation for it, inc. at your link.